# Sumif from different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file with the following sheets:

### Sheet - 1: Sheet name > January

```
 Column A      Column B         Column C  

    1          Collegues       Vacations       <----- (Column header)
    2          Collegue-1          5
    3          Collegue-2          4
    4          Collegue-3          1
    5          Collegue-4          3
    6          Collegue-5          4
```

In between there are other months.

### Sheet - 12: Sheet name > December

```
Column A      Column B         Column C  

    1          Collegues       Vacations       <----- (Column header)
    2          Collegue-3          11
    3          Collegue-6          3
    4          Collegue-4          5
    5          Collegue-2          15
    6          Collegue-7          7
```

### Sheet - 13: Sheet name > Result:

```
Column A       Column B           Column C  
    1          Collegues       Sum of Vacations       <----- (Column header)
    2          Collegue-1             ?
    3          Collegue-2             ?
    4          Collegue-3             ?
    ...................................
    15         Collegue-15            ?  
    16         Collegue-16            ?
```

### Some facts to note:

The collegues order changes month to month.
Some may leave and some new may come.
In the Sheet 13, the result sheet, I have a long list of all colleagues, both left and new.

### Final desire:

In the Sheet 13, I want to have the sume of vacations for each colleague. Is there any way to do it with Sumif, VLOOKUP, etc?

With so thanks,
Dio

Comment: You would need so called 3D formulas to solve it, however those [support only basic functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), and not `SUMIF`. You may use [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5) to consolidate your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your desired outcome in one worksheet. Your column headings would be:

Column A = Colleague Name

Column B = Jan

Column C = Feb

...

Column M = Dec

Column N = Vacation total

Devote one row under these heading for each colleague. If they didn't start till Mar, then enter 0 in the Jan and Feb cells. Similarly if they left in Aug, enter 0 all subsequent month cells. Add sum function to last cell for each colleague.

Comment: Do you mean to creat that table manually or by formula? If manually, then it is not what I want, because the table of vacations is already made and it contains information. But if you mean by means of formula, so it would be useful if you suggest me how to do it. That is not far from my desire, only if I can do it by formula. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. You don't have a table of vacations. You have twelve tables! There's possibly a way to use Vlookup on each table and then sum those results. It might be a bit cumbersome. Maybe someone else has another idea?